# npm install не работает

Tags: php, node.js, laravel, npm

Пытаюсь установить laravel/breeze, при установке npm выдает следующие ошибки, в чем дело?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Попробовал делать без символьных ссылок и сделать сразу npm run, но получил следующее [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если делаю тоже самое из под рута, то получаю вот
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39951820/4496422

Comment: @nörbörnën попробовал, добавил новый скрин

Comment: @nörbörnën я нашел подобные проблемы, но там у ребят именно директория axios отсутствовала полностью, у меня же она есть, не хватает её части

Answer (score 0):

Я нашел небольшую статейку, и она мне помогла:

Webpack 5 больше не включает автоматически полифайлы для узловых объектов, таких как Buffer и process. Однако вполне возможно, что ваш проект или одна из его зависимостей все еще требует доступа к этим переменным. Если это так, вы можете заставить Mix включить необходимые узловые полифиллы через legacyNodePolyfills вариант

Нужно добавить следующий код в файл webpack.min.js

```
mix.options({
legacyNodePolyfills: false
});
```

Имейте в виду, что это может привести к немного большему пакету. Если это возможно, выполните необходимые действия, чтобы в конечном итоге удалить эти ссылки из кода переднего плана, а затем выключите legacyNodePolyfills чтобы уменьшить размер пакета.

Comment: а что такое "полифайлы для узловых объектов"?

Comment: @nörbörnën если бы я знал)

Answer (score 0):

Смените версию php на какую-нибудь более позднюю из 8+, в последней версии laravel "соединялку"js-библиотек с laravel'ем другую поставили и под старыми версиями гайд, который представлен у них на сайте не работает